# Difference between normal looping of list and using slice?

Tags: python, list, slice

In the following two examples, I am trying to remove negative element from a list using two different types of looping.

First I tried by using normal looping `for i in list` but in this case when i do `list1.remove(elm)` the size of the list is reduce by one element. So, in the next loop the second element moves to the first element position. So, the second element is missed from testing `if elm < 0` in the next loop. So, it doesn't remove all the negative element from the list.

Secondly, I tried using slicing. What i understood from slicing is it creates a temporary list. So, when i do `for i in list2[:]` it creates a new temporary `list2 = [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]` but still I didn't get a clear picture, how it works. It removes all the negative element.

```
#!/usr/env/bin
# remove all the negative value from the list.
list1 = [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]
list2 = [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]

# Looping through the list.
for elm in list1:
    if elm < 0:
        list1.remove(elm)
print 'list1: ', list1

# Looping through the list using slice.
for elm in list2[:]:
    if elm < 0:
        list2.remove(elm)
print 'list2: ', list2

Output:-python slice.py
list1: [3, -5, 4, 7, 8]
list2: [3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Note about "What i understood from slicing is it creates a temporary list". Not really! It creates a new list, same as, e.g., `[1, 3, 6]` creates a new list, or *anything else* that creates a list. The only sense in which it's "temporary" is that, in your code, you didn't bind a name to it. So the slice becomes garbage as soon as the `for` loop is done iterating over it. Had you done, e.g., `temp = list2[:]` and iterated over `temp` instead, the copy would live for as long as `temp` remained in scope.

Comment: HI Tim, Ya if i do `temp = list2[:]` and iterate over temp, then its just like my first case. But if i loop on `list2[:]` and remove from list2, which means loop over the temp list and remove from the original list. Any way thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that iterating through a list and modifying it at the same time can produce some bad results.

For example, if you are at index 2, and remove a negative number there, the value at index 3 will move to index 2. On the next iteration, you will go to index 3, but skip the value at the old index 3 (new index 2).

The slice creates a copy, and so it is untouched, even as you remove negatives.

FYI, another possibility is

```
filter(lambda x: x >= 0, list2)
```

or

```
[x for x in list2 if x >= 0]
```

EDIT:

Here are the iterations.

```
(index)        list1            elem
   0      [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]     -1
   1      [3,-2,-5,4,7,8]        -2
   2      [3,-5,4,7,8]            4
   3      [3,4,7,8]               8
```

Do you see how we missed several values because we were iterating and modifying the same thing?

Now with the slice, which creates a copy,

```
(index)        (copy)             list2            elem
   0     [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]  [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]     -1
   1     [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]  [3,-2,-5,4,7,8]         3
   2     [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]  [3,-2,-5,4,7,8]        -2
   3     [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]  [3,-5,4,7,8]           -5
   4     [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]  [3,4,7,8]               4
   5     [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]  [3,4,7,8]               7
   6     [-1,3,-2,-5,4,7,8]  [3,4,7,8]               8
```

We iterate through all seven values, without skipping any.

FYI, `list2[:]` is equivalent to `list2[0:len(list2):1]` or `list(list2)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a list comprehension here to either create a new list containing the elements you want to keep:

```
numbers = [-1, 3, -2, -5, 4, 7, 8]
positive = [n for n in numbers if n >= 0]
```

or to reassign the new sequence into the existing one via slice assignment:

```
numbers = [-1, 3, -2, -5, 4, 7, 8]
numbers[:] = (n for n in numbers if n >= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In list one, python is removing an item while you're iterating through it, which can lead to unexpected results, as you have seen. Watch:

```
for elm in list1:
    if elm < 0:
        list1.remove(elm)
    print list1
```

This will print:

```
[3, -2, -5, 4, 7, 8]
[3, -5, 4, 7, 8]
[3, -5, 4, 7, 8]
[3, -5, 4, 7, 8]
[3, -5, 4, 7, 8]
```

So when you python goes back to `for elm in list1` after removing an item, it will not go to the one after that, but the one before (`3`). Hence the loop.

When you make a copy, `list2[:]`, you're not actually iterating over `list2` but just a copy, hence when you remove items, you're not removing anything what you're iterating over.

Comment: Ah I got it, i remove from the old list `list2` and looping through the new list, cool thats what i was confusing with slicing. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

slicing operator copies the list you are operating on, leading to accurate result.